# Monitor every method being called

Tags: java, hadoop, methods, process

I have a particularly complex Hadoop code base with a lot of reflection that I'm looking at.

Is there a way to print, debug, or watch every monitor being called in a java process?

Or ideally, in ALL processes running on a machine....

Comment: debug using break points?!

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1):

I think [BTrace](https://kenai.com/projects/btrace) is a good tool which you can use for tracing in Java

> BTrace is a safe, dynamic tracing tool for the Java platform. **BTrace
>   can be used to dynamically trace a running Java program** (similar to
>   DTrace for OpenSolaris applications and OS). BTrace dynamically
>   instruments the classes of the target application to inject tracing
>   code ("bytecode tracing"). Tracing code is expressed in Java
>   programming language.